# Find index of the element i am clicking on in Owl-carousal

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

[image]

This is my html above, i am trying to get the index of which video i clicked on and i also need to get the href of the "owl-video" anchor tag. See the code below i tried.

> 1. To find the a"href" i tried this, which doesn't seem to work.

```
var target = $(this).closest('.article-video').index('.article-video').find('a').attr('href');
```

> 2. this is the code i tried to get the index.

```
    $('.article-video').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).closest('.article-video').index('.article-video');
        console.log(target);
    });
```

i am a beginner to Jquery, apologies for any mistake

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('.article-video').find('a').attr('href')`

Comment: Please add your html as code, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, html was very long - so i posted the screenshot. Wont make that mistake again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) For getting href in clicked context:

```
    var href = $(this).closest('.article-video').find('a').attr('href');
```

> 2) For getting the index

```
    var target = $('.article-video').index($(this).closest('.article-video'));
```